# changing the current working directory in matlab for a loop through multiple folders causes an endless loop through the folders

Tags: matlab, loops

Basically, I have a set of folders that I want to loop through in order to perform a number of analyses on the files within these folders. I wrote the code so that the current wording directory(cd) would change for each folder. This is working fine, but I'm running into problems at the end. Once the code has successfully gone through all of the folders, it starts again from the first folder and goes through all of the folders again and again. So basically I have an endless loop through these folders.

Here is the basic code I have right now.

```
parentfolder = pwd;
subjectfolder = dir(fullfile(parentfolder, '\'));
S = length(subjectfolder); 

for s = 3 : S
    foldername = subjectfolder(s).name;

    %set path to the files within the current folder
    path_to_data = pwd;

    % a whole bunch of code for analysis is here
end

%make the path go up from the current open folder to the list of folders
to go to the next folder in the list
%not even sure if i need this because when i just ran it without cd./. it still 
looped endlessly through the folders
cd./.
```

Are there any suggestions for what I could do?

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: You said - "without cd./. it still looped endlessly through the folders". How can it change path if you don't use CD? Somewhere else you must be using CD.

Comment: Is there an outer loop which encompasses the `dir` command or something?

Comment: no this is my outermost loop. so the dir command is outside all of the loops. which is why I'm so confused...